# Having two methods of doing the same thing

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I have some SQL scalar value functions and some stored procedures to do some tasks which I call from many other stored procedures and from `SqlCommands` within C# code. Sometime ago I start using EF in some parts, now I have some methods written in C# in a helper class that does the same thing as those common SQL functions and stored procedure. So basically I have many methods written twice, T-SQL and C# (EF+Linq). I can not let go of the SQL ones since they are used in other stored procedures!

**What's the best practice in this case to avoid the double work and to convert the old TSQL into Linq (if I should do that)?**

Comment: I've ever done something like this and finally I wrote a SqlStatement class. I replace almost all the stored-procedure calling methods with about 15 projects in a solution. Technicaly, it's not hard to do, but truly a tiring work.

Answer (score 1):

Put that functionality in one SQL function that *everyone* calls. In your C# code, you can have a helper function that calls that function for you which would be used everywhere as well.

Comment: Its hard to implement the same thing for the Scalar Value functions... I want to use Linq since it is easier and more readable as well..

Comment: @HaLaBi - I'm not sure I follow why it'd be hard. Perhaps if you could expand on what the scalar function actually does?

Comment: Have you tried importing a scalar valued function to EF before?

Comment: Why import it at all? You could always make your own helper function to be used in your C# code.

Comment: Ok, but some SQL Stored procedures needs that function as well, then I have to make two copies, SQL one to be used from stored procedures and C# one to be used from the c# helper class... that's what I want to avoid..

Comment: You can call SQL functions from SPROCs. That's why I suggested encapsulating the functionality in a SQL function. The C# helper function simply calls that SQL function.

Comment: I think it would be good to keep UDF and the linq function , i guess they need to coexists as long as stored procs need UDF and EF framework needs the linq. I suggestion put a BIG CAPS comment at UDF and Linq function so that any future update - you do not miss UDF or linq function